# Autoboxing/Auto-unboxing is not working for bounded Type parameter

Tags: java, generics, autoboxing

Here is what I am trying to do :

```
class MyNumbers<T extends Number>{

    private T[] array;

    MyNumbers(T[] array){
            this.array = array;
        }
    public void setArray(T[] array){
        this.array = array;
    }
    public T[] getArray(){

            return this.array;
        }


    public double avarage(){

            double avg =0.0;
            double sum =0.0;
            for(T t: array){
                    sum += t.doubleValue(); // working
                    sum = sum+ t; // not working

                }
                return sum/array.length;            }
}
```

As per autoboxing and unboxing rule `sum = sum+ t;` should work. but not working as T already extending with Number class .

Here is what I trying with following type:

```
public class BoundedTypeParam{

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Integer[] ints = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        MyNumbers<Integer> stats4Ints = new MyNumbers<>(ints);

        System.out.println("Avg is same : "+ stats4Ints.avarage());

    }

}
```

Any rule/concept that I am missing.

**PS. I am aware with reifiable type, erasure**

Comment: "but not working" doesn't tell us anything about what you're observing. A compile-time problem? An execution-time exception? Something else? Ideally, provide a [mcve] but *at least* provide a clear error description.

Comment: It's unclear what you expect `sum + t` to do, btw. Would you expect that to work if `t` had type `Number`?

Comment: It doesn't compile because the Compiler doesn't know the target primitive type for generic "T". And the operators `+` require a castintig to a primitive data or `String`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet since num is double primitive hence should it not convert t in double itself because the upper bound for type parameter is Number

Comment: @Mukeshkumarsaini: Nope, precisely because it's an *upper* bound. The compiler doesn't know that `T` isn't `Integer`, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with generics. It wouldn't work if you replaced T with Number.

There is no unboxing conversion from `Number` type to some primitive type, so `Number` cannot be an operand of a numeric operator.

The following code will fail to pass compilation for the exact same reason as your code - `The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Number`.

```
Number n = 5;
double sum = 0.0;
sum += n;
```

Comment: ohh! these little things always helps me to clear big picture. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not erased, and type coersion does not apply to them at all. `double[]` is never the same as `Double[]`, and neither of the two coerse to `Number[]`.

By binding type variable like this:

```
class Example<T extends Number> {
  private T[] arr;
}
```

what you actually have at runtime is:

```
class com.Example {
  private Number[] arr;
}
```

That in turn means that following code:

```
for(T t: array) {
  <...snip...>
}
```

is compiled in this code:

```
for (Number t: array) {
  <...snip...>
}
```

As you can see, there is no information about what type of number it is, and Java does not define any operators that work on `Number` classes, which evidenced by any library that did a custom Number, or even JDK itself with classes like `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`.